# Android JNI : The app crash when an object method is called

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a strange problem using JNI in Android.
I get the object method **sendClearMessage()** of my **class SecureChannel** and I call this method that return an object of my **class MessageResponse**. This object is assigned to jobject and then passed to **CallObjectMethod** to call a method of this class. Whenever i call methods of this class the app crash without useful information. I check every function that get jmethodID or jclass values so the problem is not in the way I get this parameters. This is the code:

```
jobject sendMessage(char *ID , char *Message)
{
    jboolean isError;

    jmethodID SendClearMessage = NULL;
    jmethodID GetMessageResponseMethod = NULL;
    jmethodID IsErrorMethod = NULL;

    jobject ID_String = NULL;
    jobject Message_String = NULL;

    jbyte Length_Jbyte;

    jobject MessageResponse = NULL;
    jobject ResponseString = NULL;

    if(env == NULL || context == NULL) return NULL;

    if(SecureChannel == NULL)
    {
        SecureChannel = createSecureChannel(context);
    }

    if(SecureChannel == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    ID_String = env->NewStringUTF(ID);
    Message_String = env->NewStringUTF(Message);

    SendClearMessage = getSecureChannelMethod("SendClearMessage" , "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lpkg/msg/MessageResponse;");

    if(SendClearMessage == NULL) return NULL;

    MessageResponse = env->CallObjectMethod(SecureChannel , SendClearMessage , ID_String , Message_String);

    //Check Exception throwing - DISABLED ever return true 
    /*
    if(env->ExceptionCheck() == true)
    {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        env->ExceptionClear();
        return NULL;
    }*/

    if(MessageResponse == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    IsErrorMethod = getMessageResponseMethod("isError" , "()Z");

    if(IsErrorMethod == NULL) return NULL;

    isError = env->CallBooleanMethod(MessageResponse , IsErrorMethod); //Crash HERE

    if(isError == true) return NULL;

    GetMessageResponse = getMessageResponseMethod("getMessageResponse" , "()[B");

    if(GetMessageResponseMethod == NULL) return NULL;

    return env->CallObjectMethod(MessageResponse , GetMessageResponseMethod); //Crash HERE if I comment previous CallBooleanMethod
}
```

The functions **getSecureChannelMethod** and **getMessageResponseMethod** are my functions wrote to return a jmethodID of the specified class.
If I enable exception check after sendClearMessage method is called I get ever a true value but on Logcat i can't see any exception. If I comment the call of IsError method the crash happens on the call of the other method "GetMessageResponse". If I comment both methods the app doesn't crash but i can't see the get the message response in this way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Specifically, show the top portion of the native crash that debuggerd emits (you don't need the really long dump that follows the stack backtrace), plus a bit of the log that comes immediately before it.  If you see something like "JNI Warning", that will probably point you right at the problem.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, so that you can eventually accept it and the question will seem resolved, rather than continuing to pop up as needing attention.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following: Before the SendClearMessage the connection status of the SecureChannel must be checked because the connection is asyncronous. If the connection is not checked the method is called but further call to other object cause crash probably because an unhandled exception is thrown. Indeed I have read that only methods to handle an exception must be called when the VM throws an exception:

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html